# creating multiple nodes with different exceptions with muenchian grouping

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Im trying to create multiple "products" using grouping with a xsl:key using the below example

```
<xsl:key name="product-by-pkg" match="GoodsItem" use="PackageTypeCode" 

<xsl:for-each select="GoodsItem[count(. | key('product-by-pkg', PackageTypeCode)[1]) = 1]">
      <product type="{PackageTypeCode}">
         <quantity>
              <!-- count current group -->
           <xsl:value-of select="count(key('product-by-pkg', PackageTypeCode))" />
        </quantity>
     </product>
</xsl:for-each>
```

on this source

```
<GoodsItem>
  <PackageTypeCode>PC</PackageTypeCode>
</GoodsItem>
<GoodsItem>
  <PackageTypeCode>PE</PackageTypeCode>
</GoodsItem>
<GoodsItem>
  <PackageTypeCode>PC</PackageTypeCode>
</GoodsItem>
<GoodsItem>
  <PackageTypeCode>XX</PackageTypeCode>
</GoodsItem>
<GoodsItem>
    <PackageTypeCode>OA</PackageTypeCode>
<GoodsItem>
    <PackageTypeCode>OF</PackageTypeCode>
</GoodsItem>
<GoodsItem>
    <PackageTypeCode>CW</PackageTypeCode>
</GoodsItem>
```

what im trying to do is to create a product tag using the transformation above and where the PackageTypeCodes are not YY or XX or using a pattern where the codes does not match my arguments.
Im basically looking for a for-each where PackageTypeCode !=XX kind of thing.
So i want to loop through all PackageTypeCodes where i set the argument for which Codes to create products for.
And then a second one where i Combine the "unused" ones in the first argument to a product with the @type PC

so my result would look something like

```
 <extraGoodsData>
            <product type="PE">
                <quantity>1</quantity>
            </product>
            <product type="OA">
                <quantity>1</quantity>
            </product>
            <product type="OF">
                <quantity>1</quantity>
            </product>
            <product type="CW">
                <quantity>1</quantity>
            </product>
</extraGoodsData>
```

and i want the XX to be counted towards the PC as a default so non matching to my arguments in the first iteration shall be used in the second to create

```
 <product type="PC">
    <!--quantity should be equal to the number of PC + non matching PackageTypeCodes in the first iteration-->
<quantity>3</quantity>
 </product>
```

and the final result to be like this

```
<extraGoodsData>
            <product type="PE">
                <quantity>1</quantity>
            </product>
            <product type="OA">
                <quantity>1</quantity>
            </product>
            <product type="OF">
                <quantity>1</quantity>
            </product>
            <product type="CW">
                <quantity>1</quantity>
            </product>
<!--number of PC PackageTypeCodes + non matching in the first count-->            
           <product type="PC">
                <quantity>3</quantity>
            </product>
</extraGoodsData>
```

would this be possible in XSLT1.0 ?

EDIT-------

all packageTypeCodes that does not match something i want so for example the for each should be done for everything that isequal to PE,OA,CW,OF and anything i want to add onto that. Those that are not included i.e PC,XX,YY,ZZ etc should all be combined under the PC and the quantity equal to the amount of PC+XX+YY+ZZ but under 1 product tag.

```
<!--for PE OA OF CW-->
<xsl:for-each select="GoodsItem[count(. | key('product-by-pkg', PackageTypeCode)[1]) = 1]">
      <product type="{PackageTypeCode}">
         <quantity>
              <!-- count current group -->
           <xsl:value-of select="count(key('product-by-pkg', PackageTypeCode))" />
        </quantity>
     </product>
</xsl:for-each>
```

```
<!--for PC,XX,ZZ,YY etc-->
<xsl:for-each select="GoodsItem[count(. | key('product-by-pkg', PackageTypeCode)[1]) = 1]">
      <product type="PC">
         <quantity>
             
           <xsl:value-of select="count(key('product-by-pkg', PackageTypeCode))" />
        </quantity>
     </product>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: This is quite confusing. Please state the rules more clearly. So far, the only thing I understood is that "XX" should be grouped together with "PC". But your attempts at generalization (e.g. " looking for a for-each where PackageTypeCode !=XX kind of thing") are too vague to be translated into rules.

Comment: added some clarification. i want to have two for-each with separate rules of which Codes to create products for where one takes "hardcoded" ones and the other takes everything else and sets it to PC.

Comment: @Bluewood66 I was thinking that at first but it seems unpractical to make a filter for each PackageTypeCode so i was wondering if there was a way to "generalize" where its "Take all of these" and make separate products  and then "take the rest" and make them all under PC

Comment: @ricegat I agree with you.  So, I removed my comment and added an answer below.  In 1.0 you can't compare nodes.  So . = <some node> won't work.  You have to use generate-id to compare nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you simplify the problem by making two passes: first, rename all the codes you want to group together to `PC`. Then apply Muenchian grouping to the result:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="pkg" match="package" use="."/> 

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:variable name="packages">
        <xsl:for-each select="GoodsItem">
            <package>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="PackageTypeCode='PE' or PackageTypeCode='OA' or PackageTypeCode='OF' or PackageTypeCode='CW'">
                        <xsl:value-of select="PackageTypeCode"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>PC</xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </package>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <output>
        <xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($packages)/package[count(. | key('pkg', .)[1]) = 1]">
            <product type="{.}">
                <quantity>
                    <!-- count current group -->
                    <xsl:value-of select="count(key('pkg', .))" />
                </quantity>
            </product>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

**Demo**: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/a9HjZJ

Comment: hello, this works great, this way i can also add whichever codes the customer actually wants to take into account. 
i assume there is no way around "hardcoding" which codes to take into account when doing the replace pass?

Comment: You could pass a string that contains all the "valid" codes as a parameter, e.g. `<xsl:param name="codes">|PE|OA|OF|CW|</xsl:param>` then test for `<xsl:when test="contains($codes, concat('|', PackageTypeCode, '|'))">`.

Comment: Cheers for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:msxml="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:key name="product-by-pkg" match="GoodsItem" use="PackageTypeCode"/>

  <!-- I modified the code to handle dynamic exceptions.  You
       need to created the exceptionList in this format from what ever source you have.  -->
  <xsl:variable name="exceptions">
    <xsl:element name="PackageTypeCode">XX</xsl:element>
    <xsl:element name="PackageTypeCode">YY</xsl:element>
  </xsl:variable>

  <!-- Use whatever namespace you have set up.  I am using msxml.  -->
  <xsl:variable name="exceptionList" select="msxml:node-set($exceptions)"/>

  <!-- I added root to you xml.  Use whatever parent node you have.  -->
  <xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:for-each select="GoodsItem[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('product-by-pkg', PackageTypeCode)[not(PackageTypeCode = $exceptionList/PackageTypeCode)][1])]">
        <xsl:element name="product">
          <xsl:attribute name="type">
            <xsl:value-of select="PackageTypeCode"/>
          </xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:element name="quantity">
            <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="PackageTypeCode = 'PC'">
                <xsl:value-of select="count(key('product-by-pkg', PackageTypeCode)) + count(key('product-by-pkg', $exceptionList/PackageTypeCode))" />
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="count(key('product-by-pkg', PackageTypeCode))" />
              </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
          </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>         

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: so if i want to add another "key" which isnt XX i would add + count(key('product-by-pkg', 'YY')) for example?

Comment: Yes.  That would work.  It seems like a practical approach, if  you only have a few exceptions to count.

Comment: as for now its not alot of exceptions but my preferation would be to have "unlimited" exceptions. the reason being the customer sets the codes they want to use and the rest should be defaulted to PC hence the need for the separation and its abit unclear what the exceptions can be but mostly its either XX YY or just empty.

Comment: I see where you're going.  You don't really want to hard code things. 
 So, will you pass in a parameter with the customer codes?

Comment: i think Michael.hor25k solution works great, that way i only need to take into account what the customer does(which i have way more control over) than what the other third party is doing. so that one seems fine even though its "hard" coded

Comment: I modified my solution to make it flexible.  Take a look at it anyway.  You will find it very flexible.  But, I'm glad you got your question answered.  :)

Comment: it looks flexible and i guess easier to read aswell.
i will talk over with my collague which one seems best and we can probably run some form of performance test aswell. it would make adding exceptions more readable thats for sure atleast instead of passing alot of "or" statements on a row. thanks for your help as well :)